# Olympus OM-D E-M10 not turning on properly

Tags: micro-four-thirds, olympus, olympus-omd

This is about a brand new, freshly unboxed Olympus OM-D E-M10. When turning on the camera, it is producing two short "clack clack" sounds, the display is turning on and the lens (kit objective, 14-42mm) starts moving out but then the lens is moving back and the camera is shutting off again. Before you can actually do anything.

Here's what we've tried so far:

- doing a full re-charge of the battery
- testing with and without an SD card in the slot
- testing with different SD cards
- testing the body without the lens attached

Unfortunately nothing helped. Did anyone experience a similar problem, is there anything we can do except returning the camera for an exchange?

Comment: Sounds like it might need a repair (or exchange if the vendor will do it).

Comment: That's what I thought. We've been trying to avoid this as the vendor didn't have another E-M10 kit on stock and time's running short...

Comment: See if they'll refund you instead and buy elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in fact to exchange the camera by the retailer - they agreed that this is definitely a dead-on-arrival. Problem solved.